# Filtering RecyclerView cards when NavigationView menu item selected

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, navigationview

I have an Activity with the design support NavigationView implementation.
The drawer has 3 menu items : Home, Sort by X, Sort by Y.
My activity displays a RecyclerView with cards that shows data from a List.
The list has objects that have a String tag ("X" or "Y").
I need to sort the RecyclerView by this tag when respective menu item is selected.

MyActivity activity:

I get an NPE when I call the setFilter method from the Home fragment.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .
    .
    .
    init();
}

private void init() {
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Home homeFrag = new Home();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    if(!menuItem.isChecked()) {
                        setFragment(new Home());
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_x:
                    if(!menuItem.isChecked()) {
                        homeFrag.setFilter("X");
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_y:
                    if(!menuItem.isChecked()) {
                        homeFrag.setFilter("Y");
                    }
                    break;
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            mToolbar.setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Home fragment:

I get an NPE in the setFilter() method at filteredObjects.clear() and if I remove it I get the NPE at the for loop.

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

List<Object> objects;
List<Object> filteredObjects;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    .
    .
    .
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    objects = new ArrayList<>();
    filteredObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    initializeData(objects);
    initializeAdapter(objects);
    return v;
}

public void setFilter(String queryText) {
    queryText = queryText.toLowerCase();

    filteredObjects.clear();    // I get a NullPointerException here

    for (Object item : objects) {
        final String text = item.tag.toLowerCase();
        if (text.equals(queryText))
            filteredObjects.add(item);
    }
    initializeAdapter(filteredObjects);
}

private void initializeAdapter(List<Object> list){
    RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(list);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void initializeData(List<Object> list){

    list.add(new Object("Object 1", "X"));
    list.add(new Object("Object 2", "Y"));
    list.add(new Object("Object 3", "X"));
    list.add(new Object("Object 4", "X"));
    list.add(new Object("Object 5", "Y"));
    list.add(new Object("Object 6", "Y"));
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
com.experiments.material E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.experiments.material, PID: 32273
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.experiments.material.Home.setFilter(Home.java:170)
            at com.experiments.material.MyActivity$2.onNavigationItemSelected(MyActivity.java:134)
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:136)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.onItemClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:179)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1152)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3014)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3865)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:
activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" >

            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:name="com.experiments.material.Home"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_layout" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post logcat, add `Caused by` part too.

Your fragment will be always null, if it's not visible, so `setFilter` won't work. Try this code:

In your Fragment:

```
private String mSetFilterString;
public Home (String filter) {
    this.mSetFilterString = filter;
}
```

In `OnCreateView`

```
if (mSetFilterString != null) {
    setFilter(mSetFilterString);
} else {
    initializeAdapter(objects);
}    
return v;
```

instead of

```
initializeAdapter(objects);
return v;
```

And in your Activity:

```
mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                if(!menuItem.isChecked()) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, (Fragment) new Home(null)).commit();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.nav_x:
                if(!menuItem.isChecked()) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, (Fragment) new Home("X")).commit();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.nav_y:
                if(!menuItem.isChecked()) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, (Fragment) new Home("Y")).commit();
                }
                break;
        }
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        mToolbar.setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        return true;
    }
});
```

---

You didn't initialize your `filteredObjects`. You have only declarated it:

```
List<Object> filteredObjects;
```

You must initialize object. Example:

```
List<Object> filteredObjects= new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that line.. no dice though.

Comment: Cant resolve getActivity().
I don't know why but i don't get a Caused By in my logcat.

Comment: Nah I can't assign a fragment to a Home instance. Incompatible types.

Comment: My mistake, use `Fragment` instead of `Home`. Your `Home` extends `Fragment`. And if you are using `support-v4` for your `Fragment`, instead of `getFragmentManager()` you need to call `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Do you have other fragments than `Home` ? Also add to your first post your `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: Added xml.
Yeah, two other empty fragments.

Comment: Ah. Ok, I haven't checked your update but your previous answer was close.
 I did a cast to the fragment `Home homeFrag = (Home) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);` and that worked!

Comment: Also, my logcats don't give me a `Caused by` part. :/

Comment: Try my code which I added in last edit. My previous code was wrong.